# How to encrypt and decrypt files using aws asymetric key using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, botocore

I need to encrypt a large file using aws asymmetric key. How to encrypt and decrypt files using aws asymetric key using python

Comment: You can use the sample programs provided with boto3 SDK. You will need to generate data key for the same.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/kms-example-encrypt-decrypt-file.html

Comment: No. I need to generate a symmetric key locally and encrypt it with the public key from kms. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Can you update the question, also would be great to understand the exact use case

Comment: The page that @Vikram linked seems appropriate. You would start by obtaining the asymmetric key. Then, pass it to `encrypt_file()`, which will also return an encrypted key. You can then provide the file and encrypted key to somebody else. They would then decrypt it by using the asymmetric key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cant use asymetric keys to encrypt large files. So generate a symetric key locally and encrypt the files then get the public part of asymetric key from the KMS. Using that public asymetric key encrypt the symetric key used to encrypt the files and save this with the encrypted files. When uploading the files to S3 upload both the encrypted file and encrypted key.

And when decrypting file in s3 first decrypt the symetric key file using the private asymetric key from KMS and use the decrypted symetric key to decrypt the files.